# gradle tasks not showing additional java tasks

Tags: java, gradle

I'm just getting started with Gradle and have been making a blank project, within it I have the build.gradle file with the text "apply plugin: "java""

While i am running the command gradle tasks within the same directory as the build file, the java related tasks arent showing and I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong? Any ideas?

[directory with build file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA5io.png)

[build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptls3.png)

[resulting tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZydvJ.png)

Comment: What is java related tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Rename `build.gradle.txt` to `build.gradle`.  If you don't want to rename the file you can execute `gradle tasks -b build.gradle.txt`

Gradle doesn't need a `build.gradle` file to have tasks, for example, the `init` task creates `build.gradle`.  You're seeing the default tasks.

Comment: In the file explorer it is named build.gradle how do i remove .txt, it only shows build.gradle.txt when using dir

Comment: @bjacob596 This will show you how to display file extensions in Windows: https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/